# Property updated in base controller is not updated in home controller (derived class)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC app (with Kentico Cloud) and want to extend it to support two languages.
I want to store language selection in a cookie. I created base controller that contains a method that gets the cookie.

Working with Kentico Cloud I need to pass the current language code whenever I want to display any content on a page, this means I need to read the same cookie multiple times.

My idea was to store a cookie in base class property. When the language is switched, the cookie and the property would be updated, so the value is always up-to-date. Whenever the cookie is needed, I would simply read the property instead of getting the cookie over and over again.

This is to make the solution easier to work with and a bit more readable.

The problem I'm facing is that when I switch a language, the cookie and the property are updated in base controller, however when I then call the Index Action of controller, the value of the property has not been updated.

My question is why? Where is the mistake in my thinking?
The code looks like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
public string CurrentLanguage { get; set; }

public void UpdateLocalizationCookie(string languageCode)
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["current_language"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Value = languageCode;
    }
    else
    {
        var newCookie = new HttpCookie("current_language", languageCode);
        Response.AppendCookie(newCookie);
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(languageCode);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(languageCode);

    CurrentLanguage = languageCode;
}
public void ReadLocalizationCookie(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request != null)
    {
        var cookie = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["current_language"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            CurrentLanguage = cookie.Value;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Return default language code
    CurrentLanguage = "nl-NL";
}
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    ReadLocalizationCookie(requestContext);
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string language)
{
    UpdateLocalizationCookie(language);

    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    HomePageModel viewModel = await _homeRepository.GetHomepage(CurrentLanguage);
    viewModel.LatestNewsPanel.NewsItems = await _newsRepository.GetAllNews(CurrentLanguage);
    SetMetadata(viewModel.Metadata);
    ViewBag.Menu = Resources.Menu.Home;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: If you debug the `HomeController` what is the value of `CurrentLanguage`? I am not 100% certain, but it could be that a new instance of `HomeController` is created and therefore the `CurrentLanguage` property is not correctly initialised/set.

Comment: Well, in constructor the value is null, after Initialize method call, the value is set to default "nl-NL"

Comment: When I debug it, the value of CurrentLanguage is set to "en-US" in UpdateLocalizationCookie method call and then when HomeController's index action method is called the value is still "nl-NL"

Comment: Your ReadCookie() ends with a forced "nl-NL".

Comment: I updated the code but still the value is not what it should be.